# MYSQL Upper function

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `user_pwd` FROM (`td_user`) WHERE UPPER(user_name) = 'simmyp' AND  `status` = 'A'
```

In the db, user_name is stored as `simmyp`. The above query should not yield any result as `SIMMYP != simmyp`,but it displays records for `simmyp`. Why is it so? I am using `utf8_general_ci`.

Note: I would be using `upper` on both sides, but I would like to know how `upper` functions in the above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using utf8_general_ci - you answered your own question! "ci" stands for Case Insensitive.

What you can do then, is:

```
SELECT `user_pwd` FROM (`td_user`) WHERE BINARY UPPER(user_name) = 'simmyp**' AND `status` = 'A'
```

or append `COLLATE utf8_bin` to your query.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply.Is it ok if I use utf8_general_ci for my database? Which is better?

Comment: There's not really an answer to this except: what do you plan on doing with the database? Does case sensitivity matter in the future?

It's really up to YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COLLATE` operator :)

```
SELECT `user_pwd` FROM (`td_user`)
WHERE `status` = 'A' AND UPPER(user_name) LIKE 'simmyp' COLLATE utf8_bin
```